# Как сделать ссылку невалидню спустя определённого кол-во времени

Tags: python

Как во flask сделать ссылку недействительной спустя определе́нного количества времени, но отче́т должен пойти после того, когда на нее́ перешли более одного раза

Answer (score 1):

Там где хранишь ссылку добавь поле времени первого перехода. При втором переходе сравнивай это время и выдавай 404 когда время истекло

Comment: Можете дать пример? Просто я нигде ее́ не храню и не знаю как сделать это

Comment: А как вы её создаёте, если не храните нигде?